# - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent not firing

Tags: cocoa, mouse, nsevent

I have got :

- myViewController.m
- myViewController.h
- myView.xib

In myViewController.m, I added the following :

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {   
    NSLog(@"mouseDown: entered");
}
```

When I click somewhere on the view (myView.xib), I never enter the mouseDown: method... Do you know why ?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement `mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` method inside a class (e.g., `MyView`) that inherits from `NSView` (or `NSResponder` to be precise). Then set the class of the View in the xib file to the class you just created.

In general, class names start with a capital letter.

Comment: But `NSViewController` **does** inherit from `NSResponder`. The real issue is that `NSViewController` instances are not automatically added to the responder chain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers goetz and Bavarious. I did as goetz says and it works very well. Nevertheless, it complicates a little bit my code. Bavarious : can you tell me how I can add my view controller to the responder chain of my view ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Update: If you link on 10.10+ NSViewController now automatically adds itself into the responder chain.